# How to import to the Project's Description and Owner field and Tasks' Status Manager fields into MS Project from Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

Thanks to [Rachel Hettinger's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1056632/rachel-hettinger) assistance I've been able to create a VBA macro to open an Excel workbook and create a new project from a worksheet. I am able to import to almost all of the project-level and task-level fields I need, but I did hit a roadblock. cannot import data to the project-level *Description* and *Owner* fields that I see in the Project Web App or the Task-level *Status Manager* field that I see in the client.

The following is an excerpt of how I handle the task-level fields:

```
MapEdit Name:="Map ", Create:=True, OverwriteExisting:=True, DataCategory:=0, CategoryEnabled:=True, _
    TableName:=ws.Name, FieldName:="Name", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Name", ExportFilter:="All Tasks", ImportMethod:=0, _
    HeaderRow:=True, AssignmentData:=False, TextDelimiter:=Chr$(9), TextFileOrigin:=0, UseHtmlTemplate:=False, IncludeImage:=False
MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Outline Level", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Outline_Level"
MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Created", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Created_Date"
MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Start", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Start_Date"
MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Finish", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Finish_Date"
MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="% Complete", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Percent_Complete"
MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Notes", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Notes"
MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Board Status", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Board_Status"

FileOpenEx Name:=xlFile2, ReadOnly:=False, Merge:=0, FormatID:="MSProject.ACE.14", map:="Map ", DoNotLoadFromEnterprise:=True
```

And this is a *very limited* excerpt of how I handle the project-level fields:

```
'Project Departments
x = 0       
For x = 1 To wbk.ActiveSheet.Range(colRangeAddress).Columns.Count
    If wbk.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, x) = "Directorate" Then
        dept = wbk.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, x).Value
        Exit For
    End If
Next x

'Customer
x = 0           
For x = 1 To wbk.ActiveSheet.Range(colRangeAddress).Columns.Count
    If wbk.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, x) = "Project_Customer" Then
        customer = wbk.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, x).Value
        Exit For
    End If
Next x
   
ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.SetField FieldNameToFieldConstant("Project Departments"), dept
ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.SetField FieldNameToFieldConstant("Customer"), customer

Application.FileSaveAs Name:=myPath & projName, FormatID:="MSProject.mpp" 'Name:="<>\" & projName to send to server
```

As I mentioned, I cannot import data to the project-level *Description* and *Owner* fields that I see in the Project Web App or the Task-level *Status Manager* field I see in the client. Here's where I see the *Description* and *Owner* fields in PWA:

[image]

And the *Status Manager* field in the client:

[image]

I tried importing to these fields the same ways as the others that I successfully imported to, but was not able. How can I import these three fields using VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project-level *Description* and *Owner* fields exist just in PWA and not in the schedule, so they can't be updated using VBA. It should be possible to update the database directly, but that involves a lot more effort. Speak to your dba about how to go about that.

The Status Manager field is updatable via VBA but not on the Project Summary Task. Use the same code, but at the task level. For example:

`ActiveProject.Tasks(5).SetField FieldNameToFieldConstant("Status Manager"), mgr`

Comment: Thanks Rachel. I tried this, but I'm getting "1101 : The argument value is not valid." I stepped through each task, by using `For Temp = 1 To ActiveProject.Tasks.Count`; then changing the *mgr* value with `mgr = "John Doe"`; then using your code, but with *Temp*  instead of *5* as the index, so it's `ActiveProjects.Tasks(Temp)`; then, of course, `Next Temp`. Do you know why I'm getting the 1101 error? It doesn't even make it through the first task.

Comment: All that comes to mind is that the value being set is not on the lookup list for that field. Sorry, I wish I could help more.

Comment: No worries. You've been a tremendous help to me already! Your introduction of `ActiveProjects.Tasks` was educational and useful to me in other way. I found some posts that suggest that in order for a person to be a Status Manager they need to be a resource. I added them as resources, but that didn't work. I also found other posts that suggested that it is not possible to add someone else as a Status Manager--that only they can set themselves as a Status Manager for a task. I'm getting the feeling that is the real situation. Thanks again Rachel!